# Use ARN for dynamically generated resources in Java CDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I've just started exploring the AWS-CDK to generate resources and create pipeline (CI/CD).
I was trying to hook the existing pipeline to an external github, but ran into an issue where I need to use the **connection** method.
Here I need to provide an arn for **codestar-connections**, I want to create this resource in the same *xxxStack.java* file. I'll then use this arn to be dynamically added to the **connection** method, how can I achieve this ?

Sample code:
`.input(CodePipelineSource.connection("my-org/my-app", "main", ConnectionSourceOptions.builder().connectionArn("<get-dynamically-generated-arn>").build()))`

Comment: The `ref` property of a connection contains the ARN. Just pass that.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codestarconnections.CfnConnection.html#ref

Comment: Thanks @gshpychka, appreciate your response.